# How to remove some annotations from an image?

Tags: annotations, dm-script

I have an image with periodically arranged atoms where each is marked with an oval annotation. I would like to know how to remove **some** annotations from the image. Can someone help me, please?

## EDIT after 1st answer

```
image img := GetFrontImage()
component imgdisp = ImageGetImageDisplay( img, 0 )
number count_oval = imgdisp.ComponentCountChildrenOfType(6)
okdialog("There are "+count_oval+" oval annotations")
number i
    
    for( i=1; i<=count_oval; i++)
    {   while(3<=i<=5)
         { component annot=imgdisp.ComponentGetNthChildOfType(6,0)
           annot.ComponentRemoveFromParent()
         }
    }
```

Can you please help me which part of my code is wrong, as I cannot remove some annotations that are located in the *middle*?

Answer (score 1):

To do things with annotations you can use some *simplified* coding interface as described in the reference section here:

[image]

Or you can use the "complete" interface as I'll show you below.
Annotations are one kind of `Component` in DigitalMicrograph. (Others are `ROI`, `ImageDisplay` and the *root* of an `ImageDocument`). You find all the needed commands here (F1 Help):

[image]

```
// Get the imageDisplay from the image
// (It is the "parent" component of all things displayed on the image.)
image img := GetFrontImage()
imageDisplay disp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)

// If you want to remove components of a specific type
number annoType = 5 // Box
number nBoxAnno = disp.ComponentCountChildrenOfType( annoType )
OKDialog( "There are " + nBoxAnno + " annotations of type " + annoType + ".\nRemove them now." )
for( number i = 0; i<nBoxAnno; i++ )
{
    // Get first existing component of a specific type
    component boxComp = disp.ComponentGetNthChildOfType( annoType, 0 )  
    // Remove it from its parent component (the imageDisplay)
    boxComp.ComponentRemoveFromParent()
}

// If you want to remove all components of a specific type
number nAllAnno = disp.ComponentCountChildren()
OKDialog( "There are " + nAllAnno + " child components.\nRemove them now." )
for( number i = 0; i<nAllAnno; i++ )
{
    // Get first existing component 
    component anyComp = disp.ComponentGetChild( 0 ) 
    // Remove it from its parent component (the imageDisplay)
    anyComp.ComponentRemoveFromParent()
}
```

> In the example I've removed *all* annotations of one type. If you want to remove *some* of them, then you need to modify the for-loop. You can perform differnt checks on the component to see if you want to remove it or not.

---

### Some wider explanation for better understanding:

You need to know that each `Image` is the data in memory (plus calibration, and tags). Each `Image` can have one or more `ImageDisplays` which are the objects responsible for showing the data on the screen. (As Raster, LinePlot, Spreadsheet...). The overall obejct which gets written to the harddrive is the `ImageDocument`.

Each `ImageDisplay` is associated with exactly one `Image` (the data), but each `Image` may have more than one independent `ImageDisplay`. An `Image` can exist without an `ImageDisplay` (It is then just invisible in memory and will be removed from memory when a script ends.) An `ImageDisplay` can not exist without an `Image`.

Each `ImageDocument` contains multiple `ImageDisplays` (plus the associated `Images`). An `ImageDocument` can also contain no 'ImageDisplay' - it is an empty page then.

In the 'normal' simple case, when you create an `image` in a script, it is first invisible and without `ImageDisplay` and without `ImageDocument`, but when you display it for the first time, the `ImageDisplay` and the `ImageDocument` is created automatically:

```
image img := RealImage( "Test", 4, 100, 100 )
// imageDisplay disp1 = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0) // Does not work yet!
img.ShowImage()

imageDisplay disp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0) 
imageDocument doc = img.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument() // Always works
```

Now, as said ealier, annotations are just one kind of `component` - as is the `imageDisplay` itself -, so all commands for `components` can be used. Any 'component' can have child-components (building up a tree). So you first need to find the *parent*, then you can count the number of children - either all, or those of a specific type - and iterate to get them. You can then modify them (colors etc.) or *remove* them from their parent as shown above.

> *Why is it so complicated?* 
>  Because it is a very general and flexible concept!

**Example 1**: You can have one image(display) which has another image(display) as a child. You get such a thing, when you CopyPaste one image onto the other:

[image]

**Example 2**: You can have a single `image` (data) with two *differnt* and independent `imageDisplays` - so you can display the same data simultaneously as a spread-sheet and a raster-image.

**Example 3**: You can have a single `ROI` (which is also a `component`) sitting on two different `imageDisplays` simultaneously. If you move 'one', the 'other' also moves:

```
image img1 := RealImage( "img1", 4, 100, 100 )
image img2 := RealImage( "img2", 4, 100, 100 )
ROI theROI = NewROI()
theROI.ROISetVolatile(0)
theROI.ROISetRectangle( 10, 10, 30, 30 )
img1.ShowImage()
img2.ShowImage()
img1.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ImageDisplayAddROI( theROI )
img2.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ImageDisplayAddROI( theROI )
```

I encourige you to 'play' with the concepts of `image`, `imageDocument`, `imageDisplay`, `ROI` and `Component` a bit to get a better understanding of the inner workings. You will not need it for *simple* scripts, but its invaluable knowledge when you want to create more complex things as you seem to aim for.

Comment: thank you very much! As you suggested, I tried to change the loop in order to remove some annotations but it didn't go well because some annotations that I want to remove are in the *middle* (which means, say, there are 10 oval annotations and the ones that I want to remove are 3rd, 4th and 5th annotations).

My code is, as follows:

Answer (score 1):

### This answer refers to the broken example script

> You can not do a while loop the way you did.

`while( 2 <= i <= 5 )` is not a valid condition. If you need to do such a loop, it would have to be `while( (2 <= i) && ( i <= 5) )` and you need to make sure that `i` actually changes the value within the loop, or it is an infinite loop!
You bascially keep on "removing the first occurance of an oval annottaion" until there is no longer one. Then the next call doesn't find one anymore and the script crashes.

> Your script actually *only* ends because an error occurs.

Your script is perfectly fine if you just *remove* the incorrect `while` loop!

```
image img := GetFrontImage()
component imgdisp = ImageGetImageDisplay( img, 0 )
number count_oval = imgdisp.ComponentCountChildrenOfType(6)
okdialog("There are "+count_oval+" oval annotations")
number i

for( i=1; i<=count_oval; i++)
{   
    //while(3<=i<=5)  // Don't do this!
     { 
       component annot=imgdisp.ComponentGetNthChildOfType(6,0)
       annot.ComponentRemoveFromParent()
     }
}
```

Personally, I would write the code slightly differntly, but that's just a matter of style not function:

```
for( number i = 0; i<count_oval; i++)
{   
    component annot=imgdisp.ComponentGetNthChildOfType(6,0)
    annot.ComponentRemoveFromParent()
}
```

If you want to get rid of all annotions of a type, you could also not count them but just keep looking for them until all are removed:

```
number type = 6
image img := GetFrontImage()
component imgdisp = ImageGetImageDisplay( img, 0 )

while( 0 != imgdisp.ComponentCountChildrenOfType(type) )
    imgdisp.ComponentGetNthChildOfType(type,0).ComponentRemoveFromParent()
```

---

Now, if you want to remove a subset "in the middle" of a group, you have to be aware that when you remove an item, you shift the position of the remaining items down the list. Just consider the example of 4 annotations in which you want to delete the middle two. You do *not* want to delete serially at position 1 and 2 because:

- Delete at position `1`
  [anno0], *[anno1]*, [anno2], [anno3]
- Delete at position `2`
  [anno0], [anno2], *[anno3]*
- [anno0], [anno2]

  *Oups! Not what we wanted...*

So to solve this, you need to adjust your for loop. If it is a continues segment, you can just adjust the "get at" index to the first position of the range:

```
number type = 6
image img := GetFrontImage()
component imgdisp = ImageGetImageDisplay( img, 0 )
number nTotal = imgdisp.ComponentCountChildrenOfType(type)
number start = 2    // start index, so we are starting with the 3rd annotation
number nRange = 2   // We want to delete 3 annotations ( 3rd, 4th and 5th )

for( number i = 0; i < nRange; i++ )
    imgdisp.ComponentGetNthChildOfType(type,start).ComponentRemoveFromParent()
```

> Note: It is programmer's convention to start indexing with `0` as first position. You save yourself a lot of bugs if you start to conform to this convention right from the start in your own codes. (This is, f.e. also true for indexing pixels. the first pixel in an image is `(0,0)` not `(1,1)` !)

---

Finally, sometimes you need to work on *specific* components and the number of components changes - f.e. because of user interaction - so that you can not rely on indexing. You solve this issue by identifying components by their ID number. This number is unique during a session of DigitalMicrograph.
You need to 'store' the number when you identify a component. Then you can later find that component. (But you need to check, if it was found.)
This is an example:

```
number type = 6
image img := GetFrontImage()
component imgdisp = ImageGetImageDisplay( img, 0 )
number nTotal = imgdisp.ComponentCountChildrenOfType(type)

// Find the IDs of all annotations of this type 
// and store them in a tagGroup
ClearResults()
TagGroup compIDgroup = NewTagList()
for( number i = 0; i < nTotal; i++ )
{
    number cID =imgdisp.ComponentGetNthChildOfType(type,i).ComponentGetID()
    Result( "Annotation at index " + i + " has ID:" + cID + "\n" )
    compIDgroup.TagGroupInsertTagAsLong(  infinity(), cID ) // add to end of list
}

If ( TwoButtonDialog( "Show tags?", "Yes", "No" ))
    compIDgroup.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow( "cIds", 0 )

// ... do whatever which adds or removes other components

// Process "your" annotations by the ID
number nIDs = compIDgroup.TagGroupCountTags()
for ( number i = 0 ; i < nIDs; i++ )
{
    number cID
    compIDGroup.TagGroupGetIndexedTagAsLong( i, cID )
    Result( "Processing tag of ID " + cID + "\n" )
    component comp = imgDisp.ComponentGetChildByID( cID )
    if ( !comp.ComponentIsValid() )
    {
        Result( "  NOT FOUND. Skip.\n" )
        continue        // jump to next step of for-loop 
    }
    comp.ComponentRemoveFromParent()
}
```